# Exception in thread: thread target takes more arguments than given

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to run some test in parallel upon on_message callback. When my on_message callback gets called, based on some message, I create a thread to run some test and set it as daemon thread. I am passing only one argument to the target method specified in the thread. Even though I pass only one argument, I get this error

> TypeError: mymethod()takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given

```
#callback attached to paho.mqtt.client client.on_message = self.on_message
def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        if  msg.topic.startswith("hello/"):
            #set some vlaues              
        elif msg.topic.startswith("data/"):
            #set some vlaues                                 
        elif msg.topic.startswith("test/"):
            value =  msg.payload.decode("utf-8")  
            lst = value.split('-')
            test = Test()
            test._value = lst[0]
            param = lst[1]
            print (param) #prints one argument e.g. testdata
            t = Thread(target = test.mymethod, args=(param)) # passing one argument  
            t.setDaemon(True)
            t.start()

Exception in thread Thread-2:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
 TypeError: mymethod() takes 2 positional arguments but 10 were given
```

Comment: Have you tried passing args as `args=(param,)`?

Comment: where is the code for `mymethod()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error exists because of the format of the value passed to the parameter 'args'.

The args parameter accepts tuple, so the code you should use is:

```
t = Thread(target = test.mymethod, args=(param,))
```

Important part of this is the *comma* after param, which means you need to pass a sequence.

Explanation

```
>>> (2)
2
>>> (2,)
(2,)
```

Answer (score 1):

`args=(param)` does not create a tuple, as one could think. The tuple is generated by the `,`s, not by the `()`s.

You can create a one-element tuple either with `args = (param,)` or just with `args = param,` (the latter won't work within a function call and impacts readability, so avoid it.).

Comment: For the sanity of every python deverloper out there, pretty please never use the `params,` syntax to create a tuple.

Comment: I'd agree with Pjot, it seems an especially bad idea within a function call, where binding strength might mess up your day: `func(*params,) != 
func(*(params,)) `

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping something in parentheses will yield the same as directly passing it. This is especially useful in multi-line situations. Such as grouping imports.

So:

```
a = (3)
b = 3
a == 3
```

In you case, you want to pass args, as in, multiple. To make a `tuple`, the trailing comma is important!

So in your case, you need the comma ;)

```
t = Thread(target = test.mymethod, args=(param)) # param object being passed as args. Guess this has 10 items.
t = Thread(target = test.mymethod, args=(param, )) # passing a tuple with param as first and only item. So passing one args.
```

Comment: Fixed syntax, sorry about that :)